# How to assign a function to a tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to assign a `print` function in tkinter `Button`, but something goes wrong.

What should I improve?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

text = random.randint(1, 5)
root = Tk()
root.geometry('550x350')
btn = Button(root, text = 'random', bd = '5'
             command = lambda: btn(print(text))

btn.pack(side = 'top')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *something goes wrong* What exactly goes wrong? If an error occurs, what is it? If it is not working as you expected, what is your expectation?

Comment: `Button` instances aren't callable, but you're trying to do that (in the same statement that creates it, no less). All you need is `command = lambda: print(text)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small error there, `btn` is not defined within the `lambda` function, you can simply `print(text)` there.

```
btn = Button(root, text = 'random', bd = '5', command = lambda: print(text))
```

if you want to have a random number on every click you can do the following

```
btn = Button(root, text = 'random', bd = '5', command = lambda: print(random.randint(1, 5)))
```